# How to create calculation in MySQL between date and price

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm want to calculate the date to count days and calculate with price or custom price in MySQL.

This is booking table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_booking(

booking_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id int(11),
comp_id int(11),
register_number varchar(100),
booking_status int(11),
pick_date date,
drop_date date,)
```

This is vehicle table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_vehicle(
register_number varchar(100) NOT null,
vehicle_model varchar(255), 
vehicle_type varchar(255),
vehicle_price varchar(10));
```

So, like this:

```
totalprice = (pick_date - drop_date) * vehicle_price
```

Comment: I don't see a `price` column in your table...

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want to calculate a price for each booking record?

Comment: price in another table, wait i put the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join two tables on common column which seems to be `register_number` then use `datediff` to calculate the difference in days between two dates and multiply it by price to get total price for each booking:

```
select 
  b.*, 
  datediff(b.drop_date, b.pick_date) * v.price as total_price
from tbl_booking b
inner join tbl_vehicle v on
  b.register_number = v.register_number
```

Remember that you should substract later date from an earlier one (drop - pick) instead of (pick - drop) since this will give you a negative number.

Comment: `datediff(b.drop_date - b.pick_date)` will throw syntax error. It should be comma instead of `-`

Answer (score 1):

Use below :

```
DATEDIFF(pick_date , drop_date) * price
```

**DATEDIFF** will give you day different between two dates.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("2017-06-25", "2017-06-15");
```

Output will be : **10**

As you price is in another table hope you will be able to join and calculate.

Comment: Ok, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date field data into days, then subtract them, and multiply with price. Please note that the syntax can vary among the different implementations of SQL. With the correct MySQL syntax this would be:

```
SELECT (TO_DAYS(drop_date) - TO_DAYS(pick_date)) * price FROM tbl_booking;
```

Also note that according to your code, tbl_booking does not contain the price field, so you'll probably need to join with another table as well.